# Best way to record method calls to a file in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, methods, record

I'm trying to write a visualiser for some code which generates graphics for barcodes and labels. The way I want to do this is by recording the methods+parameters being run to a file, so I can play them back and see the visual output generated at each stage (so a kind of visual debugger to help me fix issues with measurements in the drawing)

I have access to the methods, and I can put anything I like in them - but I'm stuck on the best way to record the method signature being called and the parameters, especially since a lot of them are overloads etc.

Is there anything simple that will help me serialize/record actual method call information? (with a view to replay it back, so I need to programmatically load the information and call it) Perhaps something reflection-related?

Note: I'm an intern on the project I'm working on, and I'm probably not allow to introduce new assemblies etc. into the build, so I think aspect-based things requiring libraries are out. (At the same time, I'm not just asking a Q. I should be figuring out myself - this is more an additional thing I'm doing during my lunch break to help my main task)

Comment: How is what you are looking for different from logging?  You could add a line to the start of each method to log the name of the method and the parameters that were passed.

Comment: Yeah, logging would be the simplest way to do it - thing is, there are a lot of methods with quite a few overloads each (and each method takes quite a few parameters). Although I could log them out to a file and then build a reader to manually read them back in, that solution seemed quite time consuming to write and brittle ("There must be a better way!")

Comment: You could use `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` to get a reference to the `MethodBase` object for the current method.  Then call `GetParameters()` on that object to get the parameters.  The only problem with that is that you can't get the values of the parameters, just the names of the parameters.

Comment: So based on the fact that you can't get the values, I think you're back at square one.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to start from an existing profiler as a base - e.g. from http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/

Note that profilers themselves are quite complicated - for .Net they require some C++/COM knowledge - but if you start from a base like slimtune, then hopefully you'll be able to avoid this core code and will instead be able to focus on your own visualisation requirements.

Comment: Although I can't say I'll definitely be using slimtune, using an existing profiler (or debugger etc.) as a base isn't something I had thought of - thanks for the idea (I will look into slimtune more, however)

Answer (score 0):

Recording the method name itself is easy, parameters will be more difficult.  I *think* the only way to generically retrieve the parameters is to use reflection--the alternative is to have an ungodly amount of logging code where you explicitly log every parameter.

Also consider that you'll need all parameters to be serializable, and depending on how you want the file to be used (by a program vs. human readable) you might have to implement quite a bit of boilerplate serialization code.

You should really consider existing profiling tools and testing tools rather than thinking of inventing something new.  It sounds like performance tests or integration tests may be more valuable than a "playback" utility.